Program Database Toolkit(PDT) cxxparse/cxxparse4101 error while parsering a simple c++ file contains both "#include<map>" and "std::to_string"
I came accros  an error while using cxxparse/cxxparse4101 to parser a simple c++ source file. Can anyone give me a help?
c++ file:
//map.cpp
 #include<iostream>
 #include<map>
 #include<string>

 using std::string;
 using std::to_string;
 
 class A{
  public:
   int a;
   std::string tostring(){return to_string(a);}
 };

While I use command cxxparse map.cpp, the error occurs:
"map.cpp", line 6: error: namespace "std" has no member "to_string"
  using std::to_string;
             ^

"map.cpp", line 11: error: identifier "to_string" is undefined
        std::string tostring(){return to_string(a);}
                                      ^

2 errors detected in the compilation of "map.cpp".
PDT: Error: Couldn't create map.pdb: Invoking the alternate PDT parser based on EDG v4.10.1:
/home/caicadmin/xiongyongfeng/pdtoolkit-3.25.1/x86_64//bin/cxxparse4101 map.cpp
PDT: Trying edgcpfe4101 without CXXSTDOPT=--c++11
/home/caicadmin/xiongyongfeng/pdtoolkit-3.25.1/x86_64//bin/edgcpfe4101 --sys_include /home/caicadmin/xiongyongfeng/pdtoolkit-3.25.1/contrib/rose/rose-header-gen/include/g++_HEADERS   --sys_include /home/caicadmin/xiongyongfeng/pdtoolkit-3.25.1/contrib/rose/rose-header-gen/include/g++_HEADERS --sys_include /home/caicadmin/xiongyongfeng/pdtoolkit-3.25.1/contrib/rose/rose-header-gen/include/g++_HEADERS/hdrs --sys_include /home/caicadmin/xiongyongfeng/pdtoolkit-3.25.1/contrib/rose/rose-header-gen/include/g++_HEADERS/hdrs1 --sys_include /home/caicadmin/xiongyongfeng/pdtoolkit-3.25.1/contrib/rose/rose-header-gen/include/g++_HEADERS/hdrs2 --sys_include /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7 --sys_include /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/x86_64-redhat-linux --sys_include /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/backward --sys_include /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/include --sys_include /usr/local/include --sys_include /usr/include     -DPDT_PARSER -DPDT_PARSER_EDG4101 -D__GNUG__=7 -D__GNUC__=7 -D__GNUC_MINOR__=7 -D__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__=7 --preinclude rose_edg_required_macros_and_functions.h -DROSE_LANGUAGE_MODE=1   -tused --g++  --gnu_version 77700   --edg_base_dir /home/caicadmin/xiongyongfeng/pdtoolkit-3.25.1/contrib/rose/rose-header-gen      -o /tmp/pdt.caicadmin.568.il map.cpp
"map.cpp", line 6: error: namespace "std" has no member "to_string"
  using std::to_string;
             ^

"map.cpp", line 11: error: identifier "to_string" is undefined
        std::string tostring(){return to_string(a);}
                                      ^

2 errors detected in the compilation of "map.cpp".

Platfom infomation:

CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
g++ (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303

pdt configure commmand: ./configure && make &&  make install
Hope to recevie any reply.
When i comment #include<map> or not using std::to_string, cxxparse/cxxparse4101 can work. I dont know what is the reason. Maybe "-std=c++11" should added when configure pdt source code. I tried using CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11" ./configure && make && make install, but i does not work. I read carefully the README file of pdt source code, there is no instruction on how to set std=c++11 option flag.
Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Try renaming map.cpp to say source.cpp . I mention this because you say commenting #include <map> solves the issue. Maybe there is some problem with naming file map.cpp

thank you for your apply. I have tried rename map.cpp to source.cpp, but it does not work, the same error occurs. My guess is that pdt doesn't have enough support for the c++11 standard. I read the documentation on pdt website https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/pdt/downloads.php, it says "PDT contains EDG C and C++ parsers", and EDG supports C++17, C++14, C++11, and C++98/03 versions of the language.  I aslo tried #include<filesystem> which is a feature of C++17, but it can not work too.

Are you looking for a workaround or just interested in knowing why this problem occurs. Looking from your question, it sees you already know a workaround(as you mentioned you can just remove using std::to_string).

cxxparse doesn't look like it's a widespread tool and as such you will have a hard time finding someone who knows the tool and can help you. I think you'll have the best chance on an official forum or mailing list for the tool, if any exists at all.

@user12002570 I have a big c++ project which contains many c++11/c++17 features. When I use tau tools to instrument my project, the above issue occurs. It is hard and time-wasting to find and remove/modify those incompatible features.  So, I'm looking a solution that do not require extensive source code modification.

@bolov thank you for your suggestion, i will contact the developers of tau/pdt project.

Try this code:
 #include<iostream>
 #include<map>
 #include<string>

 
 class A{
  public:
   int a;
   std::string tostring(){return std::to_string(a);}
 };
 
 int main(){
     A abc;
     abc.a = 3;
     std::cout <<abc.tostring() << std::endl;
 }


OP already knows this. They mention in their post that if they remove the using std::to_string then program will work.
